# retrofit2 for multipart file upload working in one class but not multiple class

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I am using retrofit2 for multi part file upload. But when I use the below code in two forms, I get an error. I am using the code to upload profile creation and update after login. If I use this only in update profile or register page it's working fine.

My code [Client + Interface + Main class]:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}

public interface FileUploadService {

@Multipart
@POST("ProfileFileUpload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(
        @Part("authToken") RequestBody authToken,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part docFile,
        @Part("FileName") RequestBody FileName,
        @Part("TypeName") RequestBody TypeName);
}

private void executeMultipartPost(String picturePath){
    try {

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofitProfile = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                    .baseUrl("url")
                                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                    .client(httpClient)
                                    .build();

        mFileUploadService = retrofitProfile.create(FileUploadService.class);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),picturePath);
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("docFile", file.getName(), requestFile);
        RequestBody autoToken = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "xxxxxxxxxx");
        RequestBody FileName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
        RequestBody FileType = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),  "image");

        Call<ResponseBody> req = mFileUploadService.uploadFile(autoToken, body,FileName,FileType);
        req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String Response="";
                        // dont work
                        String objRes = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(objRes);
                        profileImage = jsonObject.optString("response").toString();
                        Response = jsonObject.optString("status").toString();
                        dialog.dialogBoxWithAlert(ActivityCreateAccount.this,"Alert", Response);

                    } else {
                        // works on failure
                        dialog.dialogBoxWithAlert(ActivityCreateAccount.this,"Error", "There is a error");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                progDailog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception here
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Crashlog**

> 03-13 22:32:33.447 23389-23389/com.source.websys.rwm A/art: art/runtime/entrypoints/quick/quick_trampoline_entrypoints.cc:2077] Check failed: instr_code == Instruction::INVOKE_INTERFACE || instr_code == Instruction::INVOKE_INTERFACE_RANGE Unexpected call into interface trampoline: invoke-virtual {v1, v127, v2646493288, v85, v48}, thing@13744

Comment: put your error log

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: 03-13 22:32:33.447 23389-23389/com.source.websys.rwm A/art: art/runtime/entrypoints/quick/quick_trampoline_entrypoints.cc:2077] Check failed: instr_code == Instruction::INVOKE_INTERFACE || instr_code == Instruction::INVOKE_INTERFACE_RANGE Unexpected call into interface trampoline: invoke-virtual {v1, v127, v2646493288, v85, v48}, thing@13744

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: I have the same error, someone help!